# onClick event managed from a different class with callback

Tags: java, android, callback

I am pretty new at android/java development and I am trying to process onClick events in an array of view from a "library" class but I can't figure out how it should work.

What I have so far is :

For the library :

```
public class WordArea {
    private ImageView[] imageViewArray;
    public boolean createWordTemplate(Activity myActivity, int layoutId, int numberOfLetters, int[] imageArray) {
    imageViewArray = new ImageView[10];

    // .....

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // ...
        imageViewArray[i].setClickable(true);
        layout.addView(imageViewArray[i], params);

        imageViewArray[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
                 thisIsWhereIwouldLikeTheCallbackToWork( v );
        }
    });
```

Then in my activity class I am defining objects like this :

```
private WordArea myWordArea = new WordArea();
```

And I would like to define in the activity class the method to be called by the setOnClickListener

Can anyone please help me with the code I should put in the library and in the activity class to make it work ?

Comment: sorry, to be clear you have an array of ImageViews? you want the on click method to call a function in a different class?

Comment: Yes, the array of imageViews is in a class called WordArea different from my activity class.     At the moment when the user "taps" one of the images in the imageViews array, the listener from WordArea class is called, and I would like the Activity class to also be aware of it to execute some actions.

Comment: So worldarea is not an activity?

Comment: No, it's a different class outside the activity. The idea is to be able to use in different activities.